# Does alloc_fresh_huge_page() only allocate virtual memory space but not allocate physical page?

Tags: memory-management

I'm trying to re-write hugetlb.c functions alloc_fresh_huge_page to allocate 2MB as block to my memory file system. But it looks like it only allocate virtual memory space, not really allocate physical page. Does somebody help on this? Can this function allocate physical page?

Answer (score 0):

No. Why do you want to allocate a physical page? Do that a few times and you will choke the operating system  and have it thrash itself to death.

Comment: My file system is a memory based one, and it runs on virtual memory space, so I just want to allocate block as 2MB, thus I try to use hugepage function to allocate.

Comment: One thing has nothing to do with the other. You said you wanted to allocate physcical memory. That's device driver territory. Might be better to ask a question about the problem you are trying to solve, instead of how to implement a solution to a problem you haven't explained, and so has us all scratching our heads vigorously saying useful things like Huh?